# Play framework: too large executable

Tags: deployment, playframework

For deployment, I use "dist" command of play console, it produces zip, I copy it to the server and run it.

But problem is that produced archive if large: ~40MB, so it takes time to copy this file to remote server, and it slows me. (I need frequent update on the server, science often I need to show results to designers/another people during conversation, etc)

I came from PHP world, where deployment is simple copy (or git push/pull) of source files.

What is best practice in play framework to achieve faster deployment cycle?

Comment: And what's wrong with my question? Why somebody down voted it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you setup the environment on remote server for play and copy just the classes with your update and run this with ssh.